# Why sending data to no buffered chan will block the go routine

Tags: go

when you run follow code:

```
func l(ch chan int)  {
    println("l being")
    ch<-1

    println("l after write")
    time.Sleep(time.Second*1)
    println("l goroutine down")
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go l(c)
    println("main")

    time.Sleep(time.Second*9)
   println("main down")
}
```

you will get follow result

```
main
l being
main down
```

It mean's that sending data to chan will block the current go routine, i am surprised of this behaviour. i know read data from chan will block go routine, and it is easy understand. but sending data to chan block go routine, i don't think it is good enough, any guys can tell me why Go-Lang have this design to help me understand? thank you so much:)

Comment: have you read https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2 ?

Comment: What is c variable that you passed to l function, before you fix the problem you should learn naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you good reminder, i really should use a good naming conventions.c just is a unbuffered channel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't show the creation of the channel so I'm assuming it's unbuffered. An unbuffered channel can't hold onto any items, so the sender blocks until the item is received. If you create a buffered channel with a buffer size of *n*, a send operation won't block unless there are *n* items in the channel that haven't been received yet. To create a buffered channel, pass the buffer size to `make` as follows:

```
c := make(chan int, 10)
```

See https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels for more information.